# Uploading audio to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I am designing an application in which we are creating ringtones from a song. How do I upload the created ringtone to Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

1. Use the [SoundCloud API](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI)
2. Create a video with your ringtone as audio (by using `AVMutableComposition` or in any other way) and upload it to Facebook using the standard API.